# Increment @instance_variable in controller each time

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax

Each time user clicks a link, I want to display him the next portion of data. I'm using an instance variable `@i` for that purpose:

```
# link in a view
<%= link_to 'Next', user_test_do_path, controller: :do, action: :list_update, user_id: 1, test_id: 2, remote: :true, HERE_WANT_TO_UPDATE_@i %>

# controller and action
class DoController < ApplicationController        
  def list_update
    @i+=1
    @cur_test = Test.where(id: params[:test_id])
    @cur_q_all = Question.where(test_id: @cur_test)
    @cur_q = @cur_q_all[@i] 
    @cur_ans_all = Answer.where(question_id: @cur_q)
  end
end
```

However, `@i` is not incremented and always stays equal to 0.
My question is: how to make value of `@i` incremented with each click on a `link_to` ?

SOLVED! This is my final working link_to:

```
<%= link_to "Next", user_test_answers_all_path(:current_i => @i), action: :list_update, controller: :do, method: :get, remote: :true %>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is that HTTP is a stateless protocol. According to definition,

> a stateless protocol is a communications protocol that treats each
>   request as an independent transaction that is unrelated to any
>   previous request so that the communication consists of independent
>   pairs of request and response.

So basically `list_update` action knows nothing about its previous state until you specify it explicitly. What you can do here is to pass your current value of iterator along with other params:

```
<%= link_to 'Next', user_test_do_path, controller: :do, action: :list_update, current_i: @i, user_id: 1, test_id: 2, remote: :true%>
```

And to take this in count when doing increment:

```
def list_update
  @i = params[:current_i].try(:to_i)
  @i = @i + 1
  ...
```

Note that `remote: true` means that you should do something on successfull `ajax` submission (e.g. replace some blocks of your html page with new data). Refer to [Working with Javascript in Rails](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/working_with_javascript_in_rails.html) for more info.

Comment: thank you! It looks easy, but still not working - `current_i: @i` in `link_to` dont changing on the new value from action `list_update` after calling this helper for some reason

Comment: do you actually mean that value of `@i` inside `list_update` remains equal to 0 ? could u place some kind of `puts @i` and `puts params[:current_i]` in `list_update` to verify their values? note that `remote: true` means that you should return some kind of `js` script and render it properly.

Comment: let me hug you!!! i found where was my mistake - it was in the path in link_to helper - i redirected user to test page (action show), but when i changed it to test/list_update action page it started to work

Comment: and for some reason when i added title 'Next' for link_to helper, it refused to work, saying `NoMethodError in DoController#list_update undefined method + for nil:NilClass`, but without it -it works fine.